# Compute $\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t e^{x(s)}ds$, where $x$ is a standard Brownian motion.

Tags: probability, integration, derivatives, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

How to compute the following differentiation? Is there a general rule that can be applied?

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t e^{x(s)}ds$$

in the case of $x=W$ where $W$ is a standard brownian motion, is there some particular facts to take into account?

if one applies the fundamental theorem of calculus :

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left( \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)dt \right)=f(x,b(x))b'(x)-f(x,a(x))a'(x)+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{d}{dx}f(x,t)dt$$

letting in our case $x=t$, $b(x)=t$, $a(x)=0$ and $f(W,t)=e^{W_t}$ we have :

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left( \int_{0}^{t}e^{W_s}ds \right)=e^{W_t}+\int_{0}^{t}\frac{d}{ds}e^{W_s}ds$$

the problem is that $\frac{d}{ds}e^{W_s}$ cannot be computed as a borwian motion is not derivable.

any help?

Comment: See fundamental theorem of calculus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus

Comment: I checked this theorem, but it rather gives a rule for $ \frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x f(t)dt$. in my case it's  $ \frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t f(x(s),s)ds$

Comment: @ Dave ddd : Well no it's not and Marc is right. Best regards.

Comment: you mean it is sufficient to put $x=t$ ? what about the $f(x,t)$ depending on $x$ in my case and when $x=W$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\int_0^t e^{W_s} \, ds$$

is a pathwise integral, i.e. it is defined as

$$\int_0^t e^{W_s(\omega)} \, ds$$

for each fixed $\omega \in \Omega$. Since the Brownian motion has (almost surely) continuous sample paths, we know that $s \mapsto W_s(\omega)$ is continuous, and therefore $s \mapsto e^{W_s(\omega)}$ is continuous for each fixed $\omega \in \Omega$. Applying the fundamental theorem of calculus, we find

$$\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^t e^{W_s(\omega)} \, ds = e^{W_t(\omega)}$$

for all $\omega \in \Omega$ and $t \geq 0$.